# Dynamics 365 authentication from WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I need to create a WCF web service for pushing and pulling leads from Dynamics 365. In the Dynamics 365 SDK I can see two authentication classes. simplified connection(SDK\SampleCode\CS\GeneralProgramming\Authentication) and AuthenticatewithnoHelp (SDK\SampleCode\CS\GeneralProgramming\Authentication\AuthenticateWithNoHelp). I have tested these classes and both the methods are working. Can somebody please advise which class I need to use for the WCF service and why. which is the best one to use for integrations via WCF. I am using this service for both online and on-premise versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think those samples are the older way of doing things.

For starting a new project now you'd probably want to either use CRM's [Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt771226.aspx), or connect via CrmServiceClient, which is in the Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector library.

Using NuGet you can get the [Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly/) package and you'll be off to the races.

Here are a couple other helpful links:

[Build Windows client applications using the XRM tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn689057.aspx)

[Sample: Quick start for XRM Tooling API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn689019.aspx)

Here are various connection string examples:

CRM 2016 and Dynamics 365 online:

```
<add name="dev26" connectionString="Url=https://dev26.crm.dynamics.com; Username=user@dev26.onmicrosoft.com; Password=Pass; AuthType=Office365" />
```

On-premise with integrated security:

```
<add name="prod" connectionString="Url=http://myserver/AdventureWorksCycle;"/>
```

On-premise with credentials:

```
<add name="prod" connectionString="Url=http://myserver/AdventureWorksCycle; Domain=mydomain; Username=administrator; Password=password; AuthType=AD;"/>
```

On-premise IFD before CRM 2016:

```
<add name="prod" connectionString="Url=https://contoso.litware.com; Username=someone@litware.com; Password=password; AuthType=IFD;"/>
```

On-premise IFD for CRM 2016 and later (v8.0+)

```
<add name="prod" connectionString="ServiceUri=https://contoso.litware.com/contoso; Domain=contoso; Username=contoso\administrator; Password=password; AuthType=IFD; LoginPrompt=Never;" />
```

Comment: When I tried this in my WCF service the authentication is taking almost 10 seconds how can I reduce the authentication duration.